# What is the fastest way to add/replace a single attribute in an XML document?

Tags: xml

What is the fastest way to add/replace a single attribute in an XML document. Regexps aren't stable for use in XML documents and XSLT isn't fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

string together an XmlReader and XmlWriter and while you loop through the nodes, look for the target node you want to change.